# Is evaluating random text dangerous?

Tags: perl

I've been passing time this afternoon by generating random strings and passing them through Perl's `eval`. The scripts are strings that contain only the following characters:

```
+-*$_.,/\@()%=`
```

Is there a statistically significant risk that I break something?

Note: I don't pass it arguments like `"rm -rf /"`.

Comment: If the "too localized" is about the choice of characters, I'd love to hear answers regarding others too.

Comment: I'm interested in an explanation of what the heck `___..@)+$$` is doing.

Comment: @Rob: See [the ~random output](http://dump.gurka.se/perl-output.txt) (of `say ___..@)+$$`), I'll spoil you if you want :)

Comment: @) is an empty array, so it converts to 0. $$ is the current PID, so this is `__ .. $$`. `__` is converted to the string `"__"`, which in turn converts to `0` in numeric context, so this produces a list of `0..$$`. It won't print on its own, though it might be possible to construct something that would print using those characters.

Comment: @Rob spoiler http://codepad.org/PujDkXvH

Comment: I don't get it why someone want to create random strings and try to execute it with `eval`?

Comment: @Sid: Fun, why do you program?

Answer (score 1):

Statistically significant from a statistician's point of view, no. From a programmers point of view yes. Any percentage of risk that can be avoided is too much.

Comment: A percentage is certainly significant. With "statistically significant", I meant that I wouldn't worry if it would take a longer time than the heat death of the Universe. What risk did you find from a programmer's point of view?

Comment: Sorry @Tim Nordenfur. I am not that good a perl programmer to create a dangerous statement from the characters that you gave. However, I am suggesting that even if the chance of constructing a dangerous statement is very very low I would still be hesitant to allow such a program to execute.

Comment: are you also afraid of meteorites? :) A 10^-100 risk of losing backuped data does not justify spending a few minutes to build a sandbox.

Comment: @Tim I disagree, building a sandbox is probably a better way to spend your time than executing random (potentially dangerous) Perl 5 scripts.

Answer (score 1):

`$!` can resolve to a wide variety of strings, depending on platform and locale. So perhaps something like

```
eval "$!=$$/$.,`$!`"
```

has the potential for mischief.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I didn't write `!` in the question, but this is just the kind of response I was hoping for anyway.

Comment: There was no '!' in his sample string.  I agree though, that exposure to the shell is a risk, particularly since it exposes a whole new syntax (sh, bash, msdos, etc) of possibilities, along with close links to processes and filesystems.  There's another issue too; Special variables such as $_ and $/ could alter program behavior from a distance if it turns out this test is running as part of a larger script.  Plus, $_ and $/ provide accumulators and registers for a state machine if eval takes place in a loop.  // provides regexes too.

Comment: @DavidO: Ability to change the wrapper program is definitely worth noting. Are regexes a vulnerability in any way except for DoS?

Comment: A regex opens a new syntax of possibilities.  I'm not sure of the risks because of how complex constructs can become.  You do provide the characters necessary for capturing, which populates $1, $2, and alters $+, $&, etc within the script.  Plus a regexp has a return value, so $/ = // + // + // + // puts '4' in $/, which will make the input record separator stop on any byte in in input file equal to 4.

Comment: @DavidO: I see your point. Note that $/=4 splits on the character '4' (ASCII 52), though.

Answer (score 0):

My gut says that answering this question definitively (i.e., with an actual probability) would probably end up placing a bound on [Chaitin's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant) which is incomputable. So it's most likely not possible (mathematically speaking) to answer your question.

Why not just sandbox the Perl process if you're worried?

Comment: I don't worry about the exact probability. The reason I wrote about statistical significance is that there probably is a way to make a huge list, evaluate it in scalar context and execute the number as binary code. That's not a real risk.

Comment: @Tim, any answer without an exact probability would be speculation. It's unlikely to do something evil, but how unlikely? That's probably unknowable.